# Add X-Fowarded-For to FTP log

Tags: logging, ftp, iis-8.5, x-forwarded-for

We are using IIS 8.5 and already have advance logging for IIS sites.  But I want the same thing for FTP logs. There is no option to add a field.

Looking for something like this but for "FTP Logging".
http://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/iis-and-x-forwarded-for-header/

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: as @Steffen Ullrich suggested it's not possible to use X-Forwarded-For with FTP log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X-Forwarded-For` is a field in the HTTP header which is set by an upstream proxy. FTP is not HTTP and thus FTP cannot make use of HTTP headers. There is also no other way to provide something like `X-Forwarded-For` in FTP. And what is not there can not be logged.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I search the web and could not find anything for FTP.
In my FTP log all IP's are the same address which is our firewall proxy.  Seems like FTP needs to be updated to allow additional headers for security.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @C.Plock: *"Seems like FTP needs to be updated to allow additional headers for security."* - FTP is a protocol much older than HTTP and you can be sure that it will not be updated. FTP is a dying protocol which is usually used insecure (no SSL in most cases) and which works terrible with NAT and firewalls. Instead of expecting features from it which it does not provide you should ask yourself why you still use it.